# Layout sw600dp not detected when running tablet emulator (Pixel C)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

[image]I created two different layouts for the same Activity in my baking app:
activity_recipe.xml contains Fragment A
activity_recipe(sw600dp) contains Fragments A and B

I intend for activity_recipe(sw600dp) to run on a tablet and selected an emulator for Pixel C (2560 x 1800).

However, at run time, the application isn't picking the sw600dp/activity_recipe.xml.

I also called WindowManager and DisplayMetrics in MainActivity and it returned something resolution of 1600x2544 about...so not sure what is wrong?

Also, is there a breakpoint in the framework code I can set to see where the application is determining which layout to use at runtime?

Comment: Can you please share a pic of your res folder structure.

Comment: You also have a w600dp configuration. If sw600dp matches then per definition w600dp also matches. Maybe that is considered more specific so it gets used over sw600dp?

Comment: Remove w600dp file and keep sw600dp.

Comment: I just checked over my layout xml's.  It seems at runtime, the application picks the regular activity_recipe.xml, despite the emulator showing dimensions of 1000+ x 1000+ dpi.  Still not sure why this is happening?

Comment: If the project is hosted on Github or something, please share it